# Ruby Serialport Timeout exception

Tags: ruby, serial-port, timeout, usb, thermal-printer

I'm using the [SerialPort Ruby gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/serialport/) to write and read form a serial port, using a Ruby script "driver".

I want to run the application from both Windows and Linux Os;
btw, code here below have been tested on Windows 7.

Specifically I have to print ESC/POS text data on a thermal printer, 
attached to a host computer with a serial line (COM/USB port).

I do not have any problems WRITING data on the printer (a superb&cheap Epson TM-T20)!

But I have to manage errors/connection status READING data from the device,

by example to see if the printer if powered ON (on-line) I would ask the printer status to the printer device with some ESC/POS commnads.

The problem arise because, even if I set serial port timeouts (I mean settimg timeout parameters of SerialPort class initializer), without an exception handling, that seem not foreseen by the gem :-(, I am not able to understand if the printer is alive or powered off. See the a chunk of code:

```
begin
  printer = SerialPort.new PRINTER_SERIALPORT_NAME, BAUDRATE 

  # http://curiosity.roguepenguin.net/?p=35
  # timeouts are in milliseconds
  printer.read_timeout = 2000
  printer.write_timeout = 2000

  puts "Success for SerialPort: #{ printer.inspect }"

rescue => e
  puts "Failed to open as SerialPort: #{ e.inspect }"
end
```

With the code above, a `printer.read` in facts exit from 2000 milliseconds .. but i do not know if because I have less than expected (0) bytes back.. or because the the device is powered off..

So, I tryied using Ruby Timeout ( http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html ), running the script from Winows 7 shell, but unfortunately the code below do not run as expected (if the printer is off, the `printer.read` HANG, I mean do not exit at all :-(, and I do not have an expected `Timeout::Error` ); stange isn't it ?

```
begin
  Timeout.timeout(2) do
     puts printer.read
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts "SerialPort timeout."
rescue => e
  puts "Serialport ERROR: Failed to open: #{ e.inspect }"
end
```

Any idea to solve the point?

Thank you

giorgio

Comment: Which Ruby version are you using?

Comment: I use Ruby version 2.0 (over Windows: 2.0.0p195)

Comment: OK - just a long shot in case you were using an older Ruby in which timeouts are unreliable under certain circumstances.

Comment: yes, I'd use Ruby releases >= 2.0

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation I gather that when specifying a `read_timeout` the read operation will return immediately (non-blocking), thus never causing a `Timeout::Error` as you would expect.

Could you try setting a timeout of 0, which according to the docs will block until a byte is available and see whether Ruby will raise a `Timeout::Error`?

Or try setting no timeout at all and see whether that works.

Alternatively you could specify a negative timeout which returns immediately with whatever data are available and make a decision based on that.

Comment: thanks Rkon! tomorrow I'll do more test as you rightly suggest, and U'll feedback here

Answer (score 0):

sorry for answering to myself question, just to share some tests, also following rkhon suggestions:

premise: 
I'm now testing using Ruby 2.0 on Windows 7 with a Epson TM-T20 printer attached to the PC with a USB connection (and a serial port - USB Epson "matcher" )

About SerialPort (read) timeouts tests:

if I set:
`printer.read_timeout <= 0`

serialport read hang (do not return control)

if I set:
`printer.read_timeout > 0`

```
# read 1 byte 
printer.read(1)
```

return after read_timeout milliseconds if there arenot AVAILABLE bytes in read buffer, otherwise return immediately with the bytes read. 
Thta's ok!

BTW, it seem that serialport gem Timeouts run with priority (WINs) against Ruby language Timeouts support; that mean that if I set a `printer.read_timeout = 2000` and afterward i do

```
 # 1000 msecs
 Timeout.timeout(1) do
     puts printer.read
  end
```

nevertheless I got control back after 2000 msec...

to manage errors/connection status:
even if I can't use an exception timeout, it's be OK my side to check the power on /connection status of printer also without an explicit timeout exception...

I verified that if i send (write) to printer a DLE EOT m (STATUS request)
I get back (read) NO DATA (nil)

Hope the report  could be useful...